# How to populate the fields in browser using Java or C#

Tags: c#, java

As I have a web form I need to fill in repeatedly, can I construct a Java or C# program to populate the form automatically? For example below is a sample contact us form, I wish that when I click on the Java or C# program, the form could be filled in automatically. How to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you need to use some autotesting techology. For example: selenium (Java), watir (Ruby), watin (.net).
Those tool provide browser abstraction that help manipulate with page and controls on it.
There is little example:

```
package selenium.example;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class ExampleSearch  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // Open Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        element.sendKeys("selenium best practices");

        // Send form with element 
        element.submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a much better way to do this. Use the right tool for the right job.